# inputting multiple value of an array into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

i need help with making a loop for inputting all value inside an array into multidimensional array

first array are like this:

```
$draft = array(
           0 => array( 
               [draft] => "",
               [SKS] =>""
           ),
           N => array( 
               [draft] => "",
               [SKS] =>""
           )
```

the second array are like this

```
$csp = array(
    0 => array(//monday
        0 => array(//session 1
             0 => array( //room 405
                    0 => "", //draft 
                    1 => ""  //sks
                ),
                .
                .
                3 => array( //room 408
                    0 => "", //draft 
                    1 => ""  //sks
                )
        )
        .
        5 = array(// session extra
           0 => array( //room 405
                    0 => "", //draft 
                    1 => ""  //sks
                ),
                .
                .
                3 => array( //room 408
                    0 => "", //draft 
                    1 => ""  //sks
                )
        )
    .
    .
    .

    5 => array(//friday
        0 => array(//session 1
             0 => array( //room 405
                    0 => "", //draft 
                    1 => ""  //sks
                ),
                .
                .
                3 => array( //room 408
                    0 => "", //draft 
                    1 => ""  //sks
                )
        )
        .
        5 = array(// session extra
           0 => array( //room 405
                    0 => "", //draft 
                    1 => ""  //sks
                ),
                .
                .
                3 => array( //oom 408
                    0 => "", //draft 
                    1 => ""  //sks
                )
        )
```

i need to fill the 4 dimensional array with the value of the second array, if it reach the last row of $draft then start over from first row

```
$csp[0][0][0][0] = $draft[0]['draft'];
$csp[0][0][0][1] = $draft[0]['sks'];
$csp[0][0][1][0] = $draft[1]['draft'];
$csp[0][0][1][1] = $draft[1]['sks'];
$csp[0][0][2][0] = $draft[2]['draft'];
$csp[0][0][2][1] = $draft[2]['sks'];
.
.
$csp[N][N][N][0] = $draft[N]['draft'];
$csp[N][N][N][1] = $draft[N]['sks'];
```

i already tried using loop like this

```
    for ($i=0; $i <5 ; $i++) { //hari
    for ($j=0; $j <6 ; $j++) { //sesi
        for ($k=0; $k <4 ; $k++) { //ruang
            for ($l=0; $l <2 ; $l++) { //draft&sks
                for ($m=0; $m <count($draft) ; $m++) { 
                    $csp[$i][$j][$k][$l] = $draft[$m]['draft'];
                    if($l==2){
                    $csp[$i][$j][$k][$l] =$draft[$m]['SKS']; 
                    }
                }                                                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but only the first id and SKS are filled into the $csp

how can i achieve the looping that i need?

Comment: So basically you need to put every single `draft` in every `session` in every `week day` right?

Comment: every single draft and SKS in every room in every session in every weekday